# Emptiness and one taste

Tags: philosophy, sunyata, mind, dharmakaya

*Might* it be true that emptiness can be conceived of as the one taste of mind: that the world of mind has only one reality which is everywhere and always the same, unchanging.

Who (which groups or individuals) say so?

And: what **reasons** are there to believe it is a correct charaterisation of mind?

Comment: hey can you explain the downvote please ?

Comment: Yes of course. I downvoted the question because i think it's too philosophical in nature and might be better of asked in Philosophy SE. Asking for what "groups or individuals" says what is more of a philosophical approach. In Buddhism one does not rely on opinions, instead one go and verify or falsify phenomena for oneself through the practice of insight meditation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I agree with Lanka. At best, words can point towards truth. This question is asking if the mind can be thought of in a certain way. "The mind" is just a concept that means different things to different people. Experience through insight is what brings about understanding of the mind, not asking questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think such experiential truths should not be intellectualised. Any intellectual stance - of permanence or impermanence will be outside of non-dual reality.

Silence is the right answer. cf. [Vimalakirti sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimalakirti_Sutra#Use_of_silence) (Wikipedia).

> Vimalakīrti remains silent while discussing the subject of emptiness
>   with an assembly of bodhisattvas. The bodhisattvas give a variety of
>   answers on the question what non-duality is. Manjusri is the last
>   bodhisattva to answer, and says that "by giving an explanation they
>   have already fallen into dualism". Vimalakirti, in his turn, answers
>   with silence.

p.s. I didn't downvote, I don't object to the question.

Comment: ok that's to the point, i will think about it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If one focuses on the emptiness of things, it will be the object of the mind at that time. Those(non Buddhists) who attain the Ākiṃcanyāyatana(7th Jhana) could get the false view that sphere of Nothingness is unchanging and permanent. But it isn't.

Comment: hi, i wouldn't call "unchanging and permanent" space the reality or nature of things. i will edit the question a little, thanks :)

Comment: but unchanging is the same as permanent :)

Comment: ah i don't know how i should edit it. i was specifically asking about a supposed (hidden) nature of every realm; i was asking if the idea of emptiness can be **stated** as nothing more than the fact that the reality of all things is emptiness - that the concept of "emptiness" can be said to be the same for everything, unchanging, but cannot be **said** to be anything else at all

Comment: Everything is empty of a soul or a self. Apart from that there's a Datu called Akasa in every Rupa. But that is not unchanging.